# Get the time difference between two datetimes skipping out of office hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-difference, angular-moment

I am trying to find difference between two date time fields skipping the out of office hours

This one calculates the difference between two date  time fields

```
moment.utc(moment(data.ClosureDate).diff(moment(data.Created))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

This one works fine but I am not sure how to deduct the out of office hours

I want to take into consideration only 9AM-6PM for each day and calculate the difference

For example, if date.Created is Feb-19 7PM and date.ClosureDate is Feb-20 11AM difference should be 2 hours

Is it possible to do this using Javascript, moment or any other library?

Comment: you can do stuff like moment(date).add(1, 'hour') or moment(date).subtract(1, 'hour') so just add control flow to dictate when that should happen and in what amount

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function, which returns the result as a number of milliseconds. The formatting to `HH:mm:ss` is kept outside of it, as that will not render well when the period spans several days:

```js
function officeTimeDiff(a, b) {
    a = moment(a);
    b = moment(b);
    if (b.diff(a) < 0) return 0;
    if (a.hour() <   9) a = a.hour(9).startOf('hour');
    if (a.hour() >= 18) a = a.add(1, 'day').hour(9).startOf('hour');    
    if (b.hour() <   9) b = b.add(-1, 'day').hour(18).startOf('hour');
    if (b.hour() >= 18) b = b.hour(18).startOf('hour');
    const diff = b.clone().year(a.year()).month(a.month()).date(a.date()).diff(a);
    a = a.startOf('day');
    b = b.startOf('day');
    return diff + moment.duration(b.diff(a, 'day') * 9, 'hour').asMilliseconds();
}

console.log(moment.utc(officeTimeDiff('2018-02-19 19:22:09', '2018-02-20 11:01:08')).format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You'll have to add similar logic if you want to exclude weekend days, but this was not mentioned as requirement in your question.